# how to use erlang zlib to compress binary data with repeated uuids?

Tags: erlang, zlib, compression

The data to be compressed is an erlang binary which represents the hierarchy of a company, it has lists of departments, lists of sub-departments of every department, lists of employees of the company, lists of employees/managers of every department, as well as information of every employee/department.  Every department/employee/manager is represented by a uuid (16 bytes).  Every uuid may be repeated several times in the data.  The data can be big (companies with hundreds of departments and thousands of employees) and it has to be transferred over network.

Suppose that we have the lists of uuids of employees/managers/departments.

1. How to use erlang zlib to compress the data optimally with the lists of uuids?
2. Any better choice than zlib in this use case?

Answer (score 0):

If the object is already an Erlang object, just use `term_to_binary(Term, [{compressed, 9}])`. This will serialize the Erlang term into a binary that you can later deserialize via `binary_to_term(Bin)`. The `9` represents the compression level. Keep in mind, the compression BIFs are fairly slow, so determine, for your dataset what is best.

Comment: The data to be compressed is already of type binary().  The compressed data will be sent to a mobile device where binary_to_term() might not be available.  Actually I want to know how to compress the data more efficiently when many repeated pieces of the data are already known.